Specifying options for the DataTables component for Vue 3
I've not used DataTables with Vue3 and I cannot figure out how to specify options like paging and scroll.
I do understand how to specify option if I was creating a NEW DataTable in Javascript, but I am using ... in my template and am not sure how to address options for the HTML object.
 <DataTable
  class="display table table-hover table-striped"
  width="50%"
>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>....</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>....</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</DataTable>


I am not sure what "how to address options for the HTML object" means, exactly, but have you reviewed the documentation? Dooes that info help?

Also, are you using the DataTables component for Vue 3?
